# Using boost-python and boost version 1.59 installed from brew

Tags: boost, cmake, boost-python, macos-high-sierra

I would rather not use versions 1.59, but I am forced to because of openrave.

I installed boost and boost-python using brew. If I install the latest versions, I can compile the basic example programs no problem. However, when I install version 1.59, I can't seem to get cmake to find the libraries!!

I have a very simple cmakelists.txt file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.12 )                                                                            
PROJECT( test )                                                                                                    
SET(SOURCE                                                                                                         
 test.cpp                                                                                                          
)                                                                                                                  

find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)                                                                              

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS python27 numpy27 regex filesystem system thread iostreams date_time REQUIRED)                                                                                                                           

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)                                                                                  
message("Include dirs of Python: " ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )                                                        
message("Libs of Python: " ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )                                                                   

ADD_EXECUTABLE( test  ${SOURCE})                                                                                   

include_directories(                                                                                               
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}                                                                                          
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}                                                                                         
)                                                                                                                  
target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Initially, it couldn't find anything:

```
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
```

Then I started messing around with BOOST_INCLUDEDIR etc to get it to find everything but python27 and numpy27! In my setup I have installed

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost\@1.59/
/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python\@1.59/
```

If I do

```
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/boost\@1.59/1.59.0/include/  cmake ../
```

(where my build directory is one level below the CMakeLists.txt file), it finds boost but complains about

```
boost_python27
boost_numpy27
```

Any help at all with getting this to work would be a huge help. I'm desperately trying to build openrave on osx, but it's been a massive struggle.

Comment: What if you drop the suffix `27` from the library names? (I'm not on OSX, but if I compare the naming scheme of my 1.58 build vs 1.67, this is one obvious difference)

Comment: Yeah that was one thing. Also there is no boost-numpy? In the end I literally copied over the files in Cellar/boost-python\@1.59 into Cellar\boost\@1.59 so Cmake would find them. But now I have hit more openrave errors. That thing is a mess.

Comment: Yeah, AFAICT the numpy wrappers appeared in 1.63.